# Add css style to prevent it changing color

Tags: css

Below code attempts to prevent a href from changing color. I have added `!important` as attempt to achieve this :

```
<a href="http://www.ng.com">NG</a>
```

```
a:link, :visited, :active, :active { color: navy; !important}
a:hover, :focus { color: #FF6800;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ht6Ym/3264/

But when hover over element its color changes, have I incorrectly used?

Comment: Personally I would avoid using `!important` and just add `body` before each of the selectors. `body a:link, body a:visited` etc...

Comment: fyi `!important` is not good, it is alternative solution. can you please show me your complete css file so I can tell you the proper solution? maybe there is an issue with your `css selector`? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `!important` before semicolon:

`color: navy !important;`

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are a little off, this worked for me. Also fix the syntax of important.

```
  a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:active { color: navy!important; }
  a:hover, a:focus { color: #FF6800;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oadg1vgc/1/

Answer (score 0):

you don't actually need the `!important` declaration, as this is very much seen as hackish and you should look to be more specific instead. For example, the below doesn't use the important declaration, and yet doesn't cause an issue:

```css
a,
a:hover {
  color: black
}
```

```html
 <a href="#">link 1</a> 
<br/>
<a href="#">link 2</a> 
<br/>
<a href="#">link 3</a> 
<br/>
<a href="#">link 4</a> 
<br/>
```

---

As a reference, though, the `!important` tag should be placed before the semicolon `;` in your declarations.

```css
a:link,
:visited,
:active,
:active {
  color: navy !important;
}
a:hover,
:focus {
  color: #FF6800;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.ng.com">NG</a>
```

However, I can only stress how much this should be avoided, as it can cause issues further down the line in terms of specificity.

---

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong syntax, Fix the syntax

```
a:link, :visited, :active, :active { color: navy !important;}
```